# Find a directory by a part of its name

Tags: python, download, extract, python-zipfile

I want to extract a zip file knowing only part of its name, because this script is used for different users and therefore not the same directory name. The source is in the downloads directory so I think to specify only Downloads to find the dierctory.

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("/Downloads/file.zip", "r") as z :
    z.extractall(location)
```

But I have this error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Downloads/file.zip"
```

So I think there is a way to find the directory by specifying just "Downloads" attribute but I don't know how to do it.

Tkanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: you can use `glob` like `glob.glob('/Downloads/*/*.zip')`

Comment: I tried to create a variable integrating the glob function for name "souce" ,but when I inserted this variable in the function of zipfile I have an error message : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source'